# CakePHP 3.x Components in Subfolders

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I use Interfaces and Traits to structure more complex Components in CakePHP 3.x. Is it possible to put Component Classes into a seperate Subfolder like:

`-Controller
    ---Component
    ----Comp1
    -----Comp11Component.php
    -----Comp12Component.php
    -----Comp13Component.php
    -----Comp1Interface.php
    ----Comp2
    -----Comp21Component.php
    -----Comp22Component.php
    -----Comp2Interface.php
    ...`

The Official Documentation tells nothing about this an my tests did fail. Is there potentially a better way to structure complex Components in CakePHP 3.x?

Comment: Why would you want to do that. If you have more components, use plugins to group them together IMO.

Comment: @mark Thanks four your reply! Note that each `Com1xComponent.php` implements the Interface `Comp1Interface`. In the `Comp2` Folder it is the same. I think in Plugins I have the same problem using such a Folder-structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside whether such a structure is useful, you can easily use the `className` option when loading the component, as long as it is autoloadable, you can load whatever class from wherever you want.

So, given a matching namespace for your components, like `App\Controller\Component\Comp1` and `App\Controller\Component\Comp2`, you could load your component like this:

```
$this->loadComponent('Comp1', [
    'className' => '\App\Controller\Component\Comp1\Comp11Component'
]);
```

See also **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Aliasing Components](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#aliasing-components)**

Comment: Unfortunally it seems like you can't enter the path to the 'classname'-Attribute but only the classname. CakePHP can't find the Component if you enter the full namespace.

Comment: @Niklas I've tested it and it works just fine, if your class cannot be found, you've either specified a wrong FQN, or it isn't autoloadable because of some other mistake.

Comment: Thank you! I struggled with this problem for days. I simply forgot to add the `Component` Suffix to the classname.

Comment: Remember to define the correct name space in your component file:

namespace App\Controller\Component\Comp1\Comp11Component;

Comment: @Franz That namespace would be wrong, the classname is not ment to be in there, it should look like the ones shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question/answer but since i've tried this in CakePHP 3.8 and could not get it to work properly using @ndm his solution I'll share my solution anyway.

I got it to work this way:

```
$this->loadComponent('Comp1', [
    'className' => 'Comp1/Comp1',
]);
```

Comp1Component.php looks like this:

```
namespace App\Controller\Component\Comp1;

use Cake\Controller\Component;

class Comp1Component extends Component implements Comp1Interface {

    public function x($y){
        return true;
    }

}
```

And Comp1Interface.php:

```
namespace App\Controller\Component\Comp1;

interface Comp1Interface {

    public function x($y);

}
```